# ruby-debug install error: failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm running 1.9.2 with rails 3.

I'm using rvm.

I did:

```
sudo gem install ruby-gem
```

and got:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-debug:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/blankman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin/ruby extconf.rb
Can't handle 1.9.x yet
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/blankman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin/ruby


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/blankman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/linecache-0.43 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/blankman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/linecache-0.43/ext/gem_make.out
```

**UPDATE**

Added:

gem 'ruby-debug19'

and when running bundle install I get:

```
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Using rake (0.8.7) 
Using abstract (1.0.0) 
Using activesupport (3.0.0.rc2) 
Using builder (2.1.2) 
Using i18n (0.4.1) 
Using activemodel (3.0.0.rc2) 
Using erubis (2.6.6) 
Using rack (1.2.1) 
Using rack-mount (0.6.13) 
Using rack-test (0.5.6) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.23) 
Using actionpack (3.0.0.rc2) 
Using mime-types (1.16) 
Using polyglot (0.3.1) 
Using treetop (1.4.8) 
Using mail (2.2.7) 
Using actionmailer (3.0.0.rc2) 
Using arel (1.0.1) 
Using activerecord (3.0.0.rc2) 
Using activeresource (3.0.0.rc2) 
Using archive-tar-minitar (0.5.2) 
Using bundler (1.0.3) 
Using columnize (0.3.1) 
Using ruby_core_source (0.1.4) 
Installing linecache19 (0.5.11) with native extensions /Users/blankman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:483:in `rescue in block in build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

/Users/blankman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for vm_core.h... no
checking for vm_core.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/blankman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin/ruby
    --with-ruby-dir
    --without-ruby-dir
    --with-ruby-include
    --without-ruby-include=${ruby-dir}/include
    --with-ruby-lib
    --without-ruby-lib=${ruby-dir}/lib
/Users/blankman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@hz/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.4/lib/contrib/uri_ext.rb:268:in `block (2 levels) in read': Looking for http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.2-p14.tar.gz and all I got was a 404! (URI::NotFoundError)
    from /Users/blankman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1186:in `block in transport_request'
    from /Users/blankman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2334:in `reading_body'
    from /Users/blankman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1185:in `transport_request'
    from /Users/blankman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1169:in `request'
    from /Users/blankman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1162:in `block in request'
    from /Users/blankman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:627:in `start'
    from /Users/blankman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1160:in `request'
    from /Users/blankman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@hz/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.4/lib/contrib/uri_ext.rb:239:in `block in read'
    from /Users/blankman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@hz/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.4/lib/contrib/uri_ext.rb:286:in `connect'
    from /Users/blankman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@hz/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.4/lib/contrib/uri_ext.rb:234:in `read'
    from /Users/blankman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@hz/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.4/lib/contrib/uri_ext.rb:128:in `download'
    from /Users/blankman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@hz/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.4/lib/ruby_core_source.rb:55:in `block in create_makefile_with_core'
    from /Users/blankman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tempfile.rb:320:in `open'
    from /Users/blankman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@hz/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.4/lib/ruby_core_source.rb:51:in `create_makefile_with_core'
    from extconf.rb:20:in `<main>'
Requesting http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.2-p14.tar.gz


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/blankman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@hz/gems/linecache19-0.5.11 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/blankman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@hz/gems/linecache19-0.5.11/ext/trace_nums/gem_make.out
    from /Users/blankman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:486:in `block in build_extensions'
    from /Users/blankman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:446:in `each'
    from /Users/blankman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:446:in `build_extensions'
    from /Users/blankman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:198:in `install'
    from /Users/blankman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/source.rb:100:in `install'
    from /Users/blankman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/installer.rb:55:in `block in run'
    from /Users/blankman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `block in each'
    from /Users/blankman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
    from /Users/blankman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
    from /Users/blankman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/installer.rb:44:in `run'
    from /Users/blankman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
    from /Users/blankman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:221:in `install'
    from /Users/blankman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
    from /Users/blankman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
    from /Users/blankman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/blankman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
    from /Users/blankman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/gems/bundler-1.0.3/bin/bundle:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/blankman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
    from /Users/blankman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>'
blankmans-MacBook-Pro:hz blankman$
```

Comment: Have you solved your problem? I also get this error when using 1.9.2-head - earlier versions of 1.9.2 doesn't seem to have problems

Answer (score 50):

The problem here can be that the install script is going off to get the Ruby Header files over the web (to build the debugger gem against) but doesn't find them for the particular patch-level of Ruby you're after. This is what's going on in the output line

```
Looking for http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.2-p14.tar.gz and all I got was a 404! (URI::NotFoundError)
```

As a solution you can point to your local copy of the Ruby source which rvm has already used to build ruby on your machine. Here goes...

```
gem install ruby-debug19 -- --with-ruby-include=$rvm_path/src/ruby-1.9.2-head/
```

Many thanks to Dirk at the following link which helped solve this

- http://dirk.net/2010/04/17/ruby-debug-with-ruby-19x-and-rails-3-on-rvm/

Comment: This also works for non-rvm installs, just chage the --with-ruby-include= value to point to an extracted copy of the source.  (You may need to run as sudo in certain environments.)

Comment: Is there any solution for Windows?

Comment: SO you have to have ruby version 1.9.2 installed first?

Answer (score 14):

the ruby-debug gem is not compatible to Ruby 1.9.2. You need use the gem ruby-debug19

So change in your Gemfile to use this one

```
gem 'ruby-debug19'
```

Answer (score 3):

In your gemfile, change your ruby-debug line to this:

```
gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
```

My source is http://dirk.net/2010/04/17/ruby-debug-with-ruby-19x-and-rails-3-on-rvm/

Answer (score 1):

For windows, search your ruby dir for `vm_core.h` and then use that dir as your include path. For me, that's

```
gem install ruby-debug-base19 -- --with-ruby-include=C:\JRuby\lib\native\include\ruby-1.9.3-p392
```

Then I had to check:

```
C:\JRuby\lib\ruby\gems\shared\gems\linecache19-0.5.12\ext\trace_nums\gem_make.out
```

and move ruby/ruby.h into the include directory above.

Now I have some other error, fix it a bit later...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue (problem compiling native extensions) working in vpn behind the firewall and having http_proxy environment variable set. This case installer was unable to retrieve ruby tar file. 
I closed vpn and unset http_proxy variable and then successfully installed gem. 
I think --with-ruby-include is an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Installing gem ruby-debug-base19x also failed due to connection problems by using cntlm proxy and "--with-ruby-include" didn't worked for me. Installing the gem without a proxy worked smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

the ruby-debug gem is not compatible to Ruby 1.9.2 and later .
replace gem 'ruby-debug19' with following 
You need use the gem ruby-debug19
So change in your Gemfile to use this one

gem 'ruby-debug19'

Answer (score -1):

just use this one:

```
[sudo] gem update --system
```

Solution comes from http://rubygems.org/pages/download