# Error installing debugger-linecache in Ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-1.9.3

I need version 1.0.1 of `debugger-linecache` for a project, and I am facing the following error when trying to install.

```
trunk ☺  gem install debugger-linecache -v '1.0.1'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing debugger-linecache:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/jordanscales/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for vm_core.h... no
checking for vm_core.h... no
Makefile creation failed
**************************************************************************
No source for ruby-1.9.3-p194 provided with debugger-ruby_core_source gem.
**************************************************************************
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/jordanscales/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
    --with-ruby-dir
    --without-ruby-dir
    --with-ruby-include
    --without-ruby-include=${ruby-dir}/include
    --with-ruby-lib
    --without-ruby-lib=${ruby-dir}/lib


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/jordanscales/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/debugger-linecache-1.0.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/jordanscales/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/debugger-linecache-1.0.1/ext/trace_nums/gem_make.out
trunk ☺
```

Any help would be extremely appreciated, I have been searching but cannot find a working solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180541/ruby-debug-wont-install-build-native-extensions

Comment: @SamyDindane `trunk ☺  gem install ruby-debug-base19 --version=0.11.23
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
    Operation not permitted - /Users/jordanscales/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/linecache19-0.5.12/AUTHORS`

Comment: You don't have the permissions apparently. Try as root?

Answer (score 127):

this may help you, it works for me

```
gem install debugger-linecache -v '1.1.2' -- --with-ruby-include=$rvm_path/src/ruby-1.9.3-p286/
```

Comment: This solved it for me. Just replaced p286 with p374, which is my current patch level and I was good to go.

Comment: Thank you; you're a lifesaver. This seems like a bug in... something. Probably rvm.

Comment: If you got no source for your ruby version (binary download) then you can do `rvm fetch <ruby>`

Answer (score 100):

This error means that the selected version of `debugger` does not support your current Ruby version.  There are two solutions:

1. Update the `debugger` gem via `bundle update debugger`. New versions of `debugger` are backward-compatible with old Ruby versions, so this is the best way to fix it.
2. Downgrade your Ruby version.

Comment: If it wasn't weird, I would hug you.

Comment: most appropriate solution even today!

Comment: This is a great fix if you are using rbenv instead of RVM. Thanks.

Answer (score 34):

Update/Install the `gem debugger-ruby_core_source`,

```
gem install debugger-ruby_core_source
```

it has been corrected here : https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger-ruby_core_source/pull/7

Comment: This is the best and most elegant solution for this problem.

Answer (score 5):

The problem was that I was using gemsets incorrectly. I knew not having permissions were an issue, as under RVM I shouldn't need sudo to install anything.

`rvm gemset use global` and then a `bundle install` did the trick.

Comment: maybe you should use "ruby_project/.ruby-gemset" file to avoid issues with your gemsets.

Answer (score 4):

From the below link:

https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger/issues/50

I have installed gem **ruby-debug19** and problem solved for me as below:

```
$ bundle
... -> failed to build debugger-linecache
$ gem install ruby-debug19
$ bundle
... -> all is fine
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case problem was not related to `debugger-linecache` directly.  Either try upgrading `debugger-ruby_core_source` or downgrade Ruby by few patchlevels.

I've executed `bundle update debugger-linecache`.  Although I had its newest version in Gemfile.lock, `debugger-ruby_core_source` has been upgraded to 1.1.5 and debugger-linecache has stopped complaining.

Answer (score 2):

I installed debugger-ruby_core_source gem, based on perusing old answers here: https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger/issues/12

Answer (score 1):

If you are using rvm, then make sure the path lead to ruby, in rvm its rubies folder

**$rvm_path/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448**

```
gem install debugger-linecache -v '1.1.2'  -- --with-ruby-include=$rvm_path/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Gemfile.lock wasn't written with the same Ruby that you're trying to bundle against.

`bundle update` should work by making Bundler look at different versions.

Answer (score 0):

manually build it. it works for me 
https://gist.github.com/4060260