# Error installing debugger-linecache: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-1.9.2

I am trying to bundle install but it is showing the above error or debugger..Please find the detailed error from the terminal

```
Installing debugger-linecache (1.1.1) with native extensions
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/local/ruby/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for vm_core.h... no
checking for vm_core.h... no
Makefile creation failed
************************************************************************** 
No source for ruby-1.9.2-p0 provided with debugger-ruby_core_source gem.
**************************************************************************
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/local/ruby/bin/ruby
        --with-ruby-dir
        --without-ruby-dir
        --with-ruby-include
        --without-ruby-include=${ruby-dir}/include
        --with-ruby-lib
        --without-ruby-lib=${ruby-dir}/lib


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/debugger-linecache-1.1.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/debugger-linecache-1.1.1/ext/trace_nums/gem_make.out 

An error occured while installing debugger-linecache (1.1.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install debugger-linecache -v '1.1.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

If i type ruby-v in the terminal I get
`ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [x86_64-linux]`

If I do `gem install debugger-linecache` I still get the same error.
How this can be solved. Please help??

Comment: I faced a similar kind of issue. Can you comment out gem debugger and then run bundle install, after it succeeds, uncomment and then run bundle install again. It should run fine

Comment: I tried it.. When I uncommented it, it succeeded. After that when I uncomment gem debugger and run bundle install again it is showing error as "Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/debugger-linecache-1.1.2/.travis.yml
An error occured while installing debugger-linecache (1.1.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install debugger-linecache -v '1.1.2'` succeeds before bundling.
"

Comment: I gave sudo -i and then bundle install but still the same error result as above

Comment: gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'. Put this instead of gem debugger

Comment: I tried that. But got the error as "Installing linecache19 (0.5.12) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension"

Comment: This is my Gemfile.:- source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.2.0'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'json'
gem 'devise'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I had a very similar error, but on ruby 1.9.3. Running:

```
gem install debugger-linecache -v '1.1.2' -- --with-ruby-include=$rvm_path/src/ruby-1.9.3-p286/
```

Got it working for me. Credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12913418/641293).

Comment: For rbenv users:
`gem install debugger-linecache -v '1.1.2' --with-ruby-include=~/.rbenv/sources/xxx/xxx`
You may need to reinstall your ruby using `rbenv install x.x.x --keep` to keep a copy of the source locally. https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build#keeping-the-build-directory-after-installation

Comment: For rbenv on mac os & zsh: gem install debugger-linecache -v '1.1.2' -- --with-ruby-include=~/.rbenv/sources/xxx/xxx

Answer (score 11):

I solved similiar problem (upgrading Ruby 1.9.3 to 2.0) with simple

```
bundle update debugger
```

which as a result installed gem version 1.6.0

Comment: way better than accepted answer! this one is sustainable, will work long-term.

Answer (score 8):

Same fix, a bit more up to date

```
# check ruby version with rvm info
gem install debugger-linecache -v '1.1.2' \
-- --with-ruby-include=$rvm_path/src/ruby-1.9.3-p448
```

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 13.04 if that matters.

I had to:
gem install debugger-ruby_core_source -v 1.1.2

then:
gem install debugger

Then my bundle completed fine.

Thanks to [this comment on the issue](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger/issues/12#issuecomment-5432823).