# failer on bundle with rubber about debugger-linecache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, capistrano

i am using ec2 and rubber for deployments
not its fails for debugger-linecache
now as i said i am using cap  with rubber for easy use of ec2 deployments
now this the input he give me:

```
  * executing "cd /mnt/feelike-app-staging/releases/20130304122452 && bundle install --gemfile /mnt/feelike-app-staging/releases/20130304122452/Gemfile --path /mnt/feelike-app-staging/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test"
    servers: ["feelike-app.feelike-app-dev.tk"]
    [feelike-app.feelike-app-dev.tk] executing command
 ** [out :: feelike-app.feelike-app-dev.tk] Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
 ** [out :: feelike-app.feelike-app-dev.tk] 
 ** [out :: feelike-app.feelike-app-dev.tk] /usr/local/rubies/1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby extconf.rb
 ** [out :: feelike-app.feelike-app-dev.tk] checking for vm_core.h... no
 ** [out :: feelike-app.feelike-app-dev.tk] checking for vm_core.h... no
 ** [out :: feelike-app.feelike-app-dev.tk] Makefile creation failed
 ** [out :: feelike-app.feelike-app-dev.tk] **************************************************************************
 ** [out :: feelike-app.feelike-app-dev.tk] No source for ruby-1.9.3-p392 provided with debugger-ruby_core_source gem.
 ** [out :: feelike-app.feelike-app-dev.tk] **************************************************************************
 ** [out :: feelike-app.feelike-app-dev.tk] *** extconf.rb failed ***
 ** [out :: feelike-app.feelike-app-dev.tk] Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
 ** [out :: feelike-app.feelike-app-dev.tk] necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
 ** [out :: feelike-app.feelike-app-dev.tk] details.  You may need configuration options.
 ** [out :: feelike-app.feelike-app-dev.tk] 
 ** [out :: feelike-app.feelike-app-dev.tk] Provided configuration options:
 ** [out :: feelike-app.feelike-app-dev.tk] --with-opt-dir
 ** [out :: feelike-app.feelike-app-dev.tk] --without-opt-dir
 ** [out :: feelike-app.feelike-app-dev.tk] --with-opt-include
 ** [out :: feelike-app.feelike-app-dev.tk] --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
 ** [out :: feelike-app.feelike-app-dev.tk] --with-opt-lib
 ** [out :: feelike-app.feelike-app-dev.tk] --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
 ** [out :: feelike-app.feelike-app-dev.tk] --with-make-prog
 ** [out :: feelike-app.feelike-app-dev.tk] --without-make-prog
 ** [out :: feelike-app.feelike-app-dev.tk] --srcdir=.
 ** [out :: feelike-app.feelike-app-dev.tk] --curdir
 ** [out :: feelike-app.feelike-app-dev.tk] --ruby=/usr/local/rubies/1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby
 ** [out :: feelike-app.feelike-app-dev.tk] --with-ruby-dir
 ** [out :: feelike-app.feelike-app-dev.tk] --without-ruby-dir
 ** [out :: feelike-app.feelike-app-dev.tk] --with-ruby-include
 ** [out :: feelike-app.feelike-app-dev.tk] --without-ruby-include=${ruby-dir}/include
 ** [out :: feelike-app.feelike-app-dev.tk] --with-ruby-lib
 ** [out :: feelike-app.feelike-app-dev.tk] --without-ruby-lib=${ruby-dir}/lib
 ** [out :: feelike-app.feelike-app-dev.tk] 
 ** [out :: feelike-app.feelike-app-dev.tk] 
 ** [out :: feelike-app.feelike-app-dev.tk] Gem files will remain installed in /mnt/feelike-app-staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/debugger-linecache-1.1.2 for inspection.
 ** [out :: feelike-app.feelike-app-dev.tk] Results logged to /mnt/feelike-app-staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/debugger-linecache-1.1.2/ext/trace_nums/gem_make.out
 ** [out :: feelike-app.feelike-app-dev.tk] An error occurred while installing debugger-linecache (1.1.2), and Bundler
 ** [out :: feelike-app.feelike-app-dev.tk] cannot continue.
 ** [out :: feelike-app.feelike-app-dev.tk] Make sure that `gem install debugger-linecache -v '1.1.2'` succeeds before
 ** [out :: feelike-app.feelike-app-dev.tk] bundling.
 ** [out :: feelike-app.feelike-app-dev.tk] 
    command finished in 64109ms
failed: "/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /mnt/feelike-app-staging/releases/20130304122452 && bundle install --gemfile /mnt/feelike-app-staging/releases/20130304122452/Gemfile --path /mnt/feelike-app-staging/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test'" on feelike-app.feelike-app-dev.tk
```

now i have installed at "gem install debugger-linecache -v '1.1.2'" and still faild have no idea what to do...

Comment: Try some of these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10916784/error-installing-debugger-linecache-in-ruby-1-9-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok after long period of search found that u need install ruby-debug-base19 gem for some respons that what i missed now all work

Answer (score 1):

On your server do the following:

```
gem install debugger-linecache -v '1.1.2' -- --with-ruby-include=$rvm_path/src/ruby-1.9.3-p392/
```

**Note:** If you don't use **rvm**, change **--with-ruby-include** to correct path of your ruby source code

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue: this is how I resolved it

bundle update debugger