# ruby-debug-ide command exploading in my face

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

So I'm working on getting some sweet sweet remote debugging action on an old app and found some instructions via https://github.com/ruby-debug/ruby-debug-ide  to get my rubymine going. Installing these two gems in my Gemfile...

```
gem 'ruby-debug-base19x', '~> 0.11.32'
gem 'ruby-debug-ide'
```

gems installed fine

BUT when I load up the rdebug command i get this error...

```
$ rdebug
/home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require': /home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby_debug.so: undefined symbol: ruby_current_thread - /home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby_debug.so (LoadError)
    from /home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
    from /home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from /home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby-debug-base.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug19-0.11.6/cli/ruby-debug.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug19-0.11.6/bin/rdebug:108:in `require_relative'
    from /home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug19-0.11.6/bin/rdebug:108:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/bin/rdebug:23:in `load'
    from /home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/bin/rdebug:23:in `<main>'
```

even the full rdebug-ide command exploads in my face

```
$ rdebug-ide --host 0.0.0.0 --port 1234 --dispatcher-port 26162 -- rails s
/home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require': /home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby_debug.so: undefined symbol: ruby_current_thread - /home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby_debug.so (LoadError)
    from /home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
    from /home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from /home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby-debug-base.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
    from /home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
    from /home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from /home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.7.2/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.7.2/bin/rdebug-ide:8:in `require_relative'
    from /home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.7.2/bin/rdebug-ide:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/bin/rdebug-ide:23:in `load'
    from /home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/bin/rdebug-ide:23:in `<main>'
```

Any ideas on how to solve this mystery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so using gem list and passing grep debug I found I had some odd gems in my box

```
$ gem list | grep debug
debug_inspector (0.0.3)
debugger-linecache (1.2.0)
debugger-ruby_core_source (1.3.8)
ruby-debug-base19 (0.11.25)
ruby-debug-base19x (0.11.32)
ruby-debug-ide (0.7.2)
ruby-debug19 (0.11.6)
```

Note the two ruby-debug-base19 thingies? yeah, I suspected that might be a problem along with a few others. So doing some gem uninstall I end up with...

```
$ gem list | grep debug
debug_inspector (0.0.3)
debugger-ruby_core_source (1.3.8)
ruby-debug-base19x (0.11.32)
ruby-debug-ide (0.7.2)
```

Now when I run my debug command for rubymine it works

rdebug-ide --host 0.0.0.0 --port 1234 --dispatcher-port 26162 -- rails s

Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.7.2, ruby-debug-base19x 0.11.32, file filtering is not supported) listens on 0.0.0.0:1234

Woo Hoo!